# XSLT проверка отсутствия атрибута

Tags: xml, xslt

Немного пытаюсь использовать XSLT не по назначению, а именно вывести отчет о неправильном написании XML (после проверки XSD схемой есть некоторые тонкости, которые схема не может учитывать).

В частности, столкнулся с проблемой проверки: Если атрибут @A имеет значение false, тогда должен присутствовать атрибут @B имеющий любое значение (само значение проверится схемой).

Сделал шаблон XSLT, который добирается до нужного тега и находит атрибут @A имеющий значение 'false'. Как проверить, что в данном элементе отсутствует атрибут @B ?

Результат таких проверок формирует HTML документ с перечнем найденных ошибок.

XSLT выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:vw="tableview.xsd">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="vw:template/vw:cells/vw:block"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text() | @*">
    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="vw:block">
    <xsl:for-each select="vw:cell">
      <xsl:if test="@readonly='false' and @type = null">

        ///Здесь @type = null сам придумал. Не знаю как понять отсутствие атрибута

        <tr>
          <td>
            Атрибут readonly имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@readonly"/> и атрибут type имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Если есть какие-то замечания по коду, тоже с удовольствием выслушаю. С XSLT знакомлюсь первый день. Часть документации "быстрый старт" от msdn.microsoft почитал, но этого явно мало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примечание: для быстрого тестирования я убрал пространства имён.

Это делается следующим образом:

```
<xsl:template match="block">
  <xsl:for-each select="cell">
    <xsl:if test="@readonly='false' and @type">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Атрибут readonly имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@readonly"/>
          и атрибут type имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@readonly='false' and not(@type)">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Атрибут readonly имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@readonly"/>
          и атрибута type нет
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Более правильным является использование `choose`:

```
<xsl:template match="block">
  <xsl:for-each select="cell">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@readonly='false' and @type">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Атрибут readonly имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@readonly"/>
            и атрибут type имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Атрибут readonly имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@readonly"/>
            и атрибута type нет
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Ещё более правильным является применение отдельных шаблонов на каждое условие:

```
<xsl:template match="block/cell[@type]">
  <!-- атрибут @type есть -->
  <xsl:if test="@readonly='false'">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Атрибут readonly имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@readonly"/>
        и атрибут type имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block/cell[not(@type)]">
  <!-- атрибута @type нет -->
  <xsl:if test="@readonly='false'">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Атрибут readonly имеет значение <xsl:value-of select="@readonly"/>
        и атрибута type нет
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Аналогично можно делать проверку значения атрибута `readonly` в выражении xpath.